# Should I include the .pyc byte code when saving a project to a read-only storage?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Yes, I read some of those `.pyc` questions, but still nothing.

I need to save a project to a CD and preferably  I'd like to be able to run it right from there. 
**Should I put the `.pyc` files in there or not?**

No,

- byte-code is not version compatible

Yes

- the project is supposed to run with the same python version
- `.py` files won't be changed any more in that release
- it might be load faster
- if smth doesn't suit, python will (need to) create new `.pyc`s somewhere anyway

The latter one: Python will handle that and use a temp directory, won't it?

Comment: Avoid it unless you have a good reason.

Comment: python does not require the .pyc files, it just speeds up the import of the (unchanged) module the next time you run your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer : No Need to Include** 
***You want to Compile & Run Means :-*** 
Your question says, you are going to compile your python source code in another machine. When you compile your code, the ".pyc" file will be created. So, it is not necessary to include the ".pyc" file with your cd. If you put means, no problem, when you compile your source code in another machine, it will replace the ".pyc" file with the newly created ".pyc" file. 
***You want to Only Run Means:-***
But, if you want to run without compile means, you should convert your program into executable. Executable file may be for windows or linux. 
For Linux, to create executable file : Use "CDE" package. 
Link: http://www.pgbovine.net/cde.html 
For Windows, to create executable file : Use "Py2Exe" package 
Link : http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules 
I hope this is the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

PYC is python bytecode making the original code run faster. You can omit it, since your code will still be able to run.

However if you need to run your code on different machines, probably without any python distribution. Take a look at

- http://www.py2exe.org/ which is for windows only
- http://www.pyinstaller.org/ which is for most systems

I personally worked with py2exe, it is simple to use. Although it makes fairly huge package, since it add all python packages required to run the original python script.

Hope this is helpful for You.